# I need help to add a scrollbar in div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Hello I need help for adding a scrollbar at div id header , I try it but it doesnt work. First I want a answer why it doesnt work and second answer for fix t

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3nzw5ca/1/).. Probably you don't have enough content in the div to make a scrollbar in the div.

Comment: <img>http://prntscr.com/602qaf</img> you can see this ss , I think I have enought content. style of body affect in scrollbar? body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
overflow:hidden;
height: 100%

}

Comment: As long as you have specified overflow in the header (as you have), then the body shouldn't override it.. But you are missing a semi-colon after the height in your body css.

Comment: what you suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

```
#header{
    top:0px;
    width:1023px;
    position:fixed; 
    overflow:auto;
    height: 100px;
}
```

change **overflow:auto** to **overflow:scroll**

Comment: Doesnt work again , i can show you the code of body how it look if helps you

Answer (score 0):

I found your HTML in another thread you have created, and put it into a JSFiddle.

The problem is that your divs inside the header is fixed. Set it as relative like this, and the problem should be solved:

```
#headerLeft{
   top:0;
   position:relative;
   left:0px;
   width:630px;
   height:100px;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3nzw5ca/2/).

Comment: it works now , but the problem is that i want only 1 scrollbar for all main page. look at screenshot there are 3 scrollbar . http://prntscr.com/60419r